# How to upgrade Plotly to latest version?

Tags: python, installation, pip, plotly

a few months ago I downloaded plotly using this (book from 2018):

```
python -m pip install --user plotly
```

but basically I dont even know which version is it. How can I check it and upgreat to latest version? I have windows on my PC. On the plotly webside I found instructions how to install latest version:

```
pip install plotly==4.14.3
```

or

```
conda install -c plotly plotly=4.14.3
```

the pip from plotly webside is different than my.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to check the version of you can either do

- `pip list | grep plotly` or,
- `pip show plotly`

---

Now both `python -m pip install plotly` and `pip install plotly` pretty much do the same thing. The former is recommended because `pip` will install the package for the corresponding interpreter (i.e. `python`).

---

To upgrade `plotly` simply run

```
python -m pip install --upgrade plotly
```